# Passing an object as an argument through an external method call

Tags: java, android, object, parameter-passing

I have an object which I need to pass into an ArrayList. The ArrayList is contained within an external method, which is in another class.

I've debugged the program and know that the information being passed into the 'Application' Constructor is being put into the 'app' object. My problem is moving it from here to the 'GuestsAttending' Method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Booking Screen Method:

```
public void saveBookingInfo(View view) {
    GuestsAttending sendApplication = new GuestsAttending();

    EditText applicantNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.applicantNameTextField);
    EditText itemToBurnText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemToBurnTextField);

    String appName = applicantNameText.getText().toString();
    String appItemToBurn = itemToBurnText.getText().toString();

    if (appItemToBurn.isEmpty() || appName.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(BookingScreen.this, "Please fill in all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Application app = new Application(appItemToBurn, appName);
        sendApplication.getGuestsAttending(app);

        this.finish();
    }
}
```

GuestsAttending Method:

```
public void getGuestsAttending(Application app){
    peopleAttending.add(app);
}
```

Application Class:

```
public class Application {

    private String name;
    private String item;

    public Application(String applicantName, String applicantItem) {
        name = applicantName;
        item = applicantItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: to access `name` and `item` from `getGuestsAttending` method make both fields public or create getter-setter methods in Application class

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K I'm using the Application class to make the object, which can then be used in the getGuestsAttending method. peopleAttending is the ArrayList :) -- I'm having difficulty moving the object from one class to another because when I pass it in as a parameter, it doesn't go into the arrayList.

Comment: If you want to pass an ArrayList of some objects between Activities using a `Bundle` your object should implement either `Serializable` or `Parcellable`.

Comment: I don't know this is the exact solution try singleton class to hold Application objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, change "getGuestAttending" to "addGuestAttending". If "peopleAttending" is an array, your method won't work. Change "peopleAttending" to a List or Set, then it will work. If "peopleAttending" needs to be an array, you can't add items to it unless you declare it big enough to hold all your guests. Then you have to keep track of the number of guests, so you know where to insert new guests. In other words, don't use an array, use a List:

```
List attendingGuests = new LinkedList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution. Instead of creating the object in another class and passing it into the external method call as a parameter, I created the object within the external method, and passed a couple of strings to the method, which I passed into another classes' constructor to make the object within the method.